# Allow AWS SQS queue access across regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have an AWS SQS queue with a permissions policy that looks like this:

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:123123123:default_staging/SQSDefaultPolicy",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Sid123123123123",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "123123123123"
      },
      "Action": "SQS:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:123123123123123:default_staging"
    }
  ]
}
```

Unfortunately I can't add messages to the `default_staging` queue from an AWS server of mine in a different region.

I *can* add messages to `default_staging` from my other region if I set the permissions policy to be wide open.

How can I adjust my policy to allow the `SQS:*` action across all my regions?

Comment: I use queues across regions all the time.  There's no particular configuration needed.  The question becomes one of what you might be doing when trying to access the queue that differs from what I'm doing, which is using IAM user credentials directly.  Are you using roles instead?

Comment: I don't think I'm using either. So far the permissions have just been wide open and so I can connect because of that. Any guidance you can offer would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Sharing SQS across regions is possible via correct IAM permissions and most importantly the SQS URL that you need to supply to your AWS SDK.

Here you can find more information about [Queue and Message Identifiers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/ImportantIdentifiers.html).

Here's an example of a policy that could be applied to a queue to give an IAM user called `SQSUser` permissions on that queue:

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:123123123123:default_staging/SQSDefaultPolicy",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Sid89345945989988",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123123123123:user/SQSUser"
      },
      "Action": "SQS:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:123123123123:default_staging"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the significant part:

```json
"Principal": {
  "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123123123123:user/SQSUser"
},
```

Comment: It's funny when someone down-votes a proved working solution.

Comment: It looks so far like you're right and it is possible. I'll mark this correct when I can verify for sure.

Comment: Is this still valid?  I am looking perform something similar but have not gotten this to work.

Comment: Yes, this should still be valid since it's a core principle in AWS. What's your error?

Comment: @JasonSwett access policy like that is not enough to allow cross-region delivery, being it in the same account or cross account